# ORDER BY RANDOM() in Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying this `SQL` query to work:

```
"SELECT * FROM people WHERE gender='female' ORDER BY val, RANDOM();"
```

But, I got the following error:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) not authorized to use function: random

Is there an equivalent way to do this? If possible with a single query.

I read that Cordova / Phonegap - SQLite disables `RANDOM ()` function because it spends a lot of memory, and create temporary tables, but the table will have 800 rows maximum, and the results are filtered by `WHERE`.

***EDIT:***
I have tried to mess up the result using the following function
But then I get an error!

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var counter = array.length,
        temp, index;
    // While there are elements in the array
    while (counter > 0) {
        // Pick a random index
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;
        // And swap the last element with it
        temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
var resultArray = [];
for (var x = 0; x < results.rows.length; x += 1) {
    resultArray.push(results.rows.item(x));
}
var res = shuffle(resultArray);
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
    name = (res.rows.item(i).name);
}
```

**ERROR:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Thanks!

Comment: If you have that few rows, why not pull them in and randomize them in memory?

Comment: How can I do sorting first by "val" and then randomize them in memory?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have added more code, please check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = shuffle(resultArray);
for (var i=0; i < res.length; i++) 
{
    name = (res[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Please also explain your code to be more educative.

Comment: Basically, this is the *correct* way to access the array of arrays *randomized*, see shuffle function in my question.

Comment: I mean in your answer, not comments.