# JavaScript Array - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length'

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova, random

I'm developing a Cordova/Phonegap application that uses an internal database...
Normally I do the query, and then I read the results in this way:

```
for (var i=0;i<results.rows.length;i++)
{
     name=(results.rows.item(i).name);
     alert(name);
}
```

Since the `RANDOM()` SQLite function  has been giving me [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719899/order-by-random-in-cordova-phonegap), I decided to mess up the results myself:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var counter = array.length, temp, index;

    // While there are elements in the array
    while (counter > 0) {
        // Pick a random index
        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

        // Decrease counter by 1
        counter--;

        // And swap the last element with it
        temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}
var resultArray = [];
for(var x=0; x < results.rows.length; x+=1) {
     resultArray.push(results.rows.item(x));
}
var res = shuffle(resultArray);
for (var i=0;i<res.rows.length;i++){
     name=(res.rows.item(i).name);
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Why is this happening? And how I can solve it?
thanks!

Comment: Can you put up the code for result? Like how it is defined?

Comment: i suppose you have undefined in 'res.rows' because res is array, but res.rows isn't

Comment: If I do alert(name), 
I should see the names of the table at which I made the query.

Comment: @VasilVanchuk Thanks, Can you tell me please how I can adapt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're pushing to resultArray only items without rows,
therefor you need to traverse only via the resultArray itself.

```
resultArray.push(results.rows.item(x));
```

therefor use:

```
var res = shuffle(resultArray);
for (var i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
    name = (res[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = shuffle(resultArray);
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
     name=(res.item(i).name);
}
```

if so ?

or better

```
var res = shuffle(resultArray);
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
     name=(res[i].name);
}
```

if not - please show what you'v got in console in

```
var res = shuffle(resultArray);
console.log(res);
for (var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
     name=(res[i].name);
     console.log(res[i]);
}
```

P.S. and keep in mind, that all value set in single variable 'name' - so they kick each other

Comment: sorry, I got: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...

Comment: It will be better to show code at jsbin. Try my changed code